# Unity il2cpp code stripping change my app behavior

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play, android-app-bundle, il2cpp

In Unity when I build using mono and code stripping disabled, my app works fine.

But I can't get ARM64 with mono so I have to use il2cpp.

With il2cpp code stripping is always enabled and it changes my game behaviour. It probably deletes important code.

Google Play ask for arm64 and if I use mono that won't be possible. With il2cpp my app doesn't work as I want.

There are lots of code so I can't publish them here but do you know what kind of code that code stripping deletes.

What can I do?

Comment: Just making sure, Managed Stripping Level is set to "Low", right?

Comment: Yes. I haven't even try medium or high.

Comment: Are you using reflection in your code? Also do you have any information of which classes are getting stripped? If you do you can try to use the [Preserve] attribute. More information how to use it: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html

Comment: I have looked to this documentation but I am not quite sure how to preserve class. If you know please share with me.

Comment: @BerkeÖzkır Have you figured it out? We are hitting same problem. Mono works, il2cpp doesn't. We need 64-bit for google play store.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution? I'm having the same issue